# How to convert this image tag to work using CSS on a div?

Tags: html, css

My image tag looks like:

```
<img src="/images/blah.gif" alt="blah" />
```

I want this to work using CSS only, I tried this, but the image is not visible?

```
.blah
{
    background-image: url('/images/blah.gif') center center no-repeat #fff;    
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You need to show the div's HTML for definitive answers

Comment: Pekka has probably already answered you, but if you're not 100% clear yet, please post the code and any other styling that's attached to the div you're trying to display.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, your `div` has no content, so it won't take up space.

You'd need to give the `div` the height and width of the image you are trying to display.

There is no way to auto-resize the `div` to the dimensions of the image, like the `img` element can.

Answer (score 0):

An img tag is not a div tag. Try the following

```
<div style="background-image: url(../pathto/test-background.gif); height: 200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;">
Example of a DIV element with a background image
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a div Tag, so:

```
<div class="blah"></div>
```

now your css code:

```
.blah
{
background: url('/images/blah.gif') 0 0 no-repeat;
//remember that if you have the image in a folder, the pat will start with: ../images
}
```